# Re-require C Library In rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I re-require a C-precompiled library (*.so file in linux)?

I'm able to load the lib using

```
require 'lib_file.so'
```

but not using

```
load 'lib_file.so'
```

I've created a web interface for updating the lib file and I need to reload the file after updating to make it work. How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: What's the error? Btw, you understand that the reload function will only affect the one process handling the request in case you are using a forking web server? You should really restart the entire web server and in case this problem goes away

Comment: A re-load will not *remove* things that the old copy of the library added to the Ruby process. Instead, it will over-write things with the same name that it adds (e.g. class and method definitions). Re-loading up-dated source files in-process is a nice shortcut whilst you are developing that source and making small iterative changes. I would not recommend the same for updating libraries or any compiled gems etc . . . and absolutely not in production, you will have no way to know how much of a mess you have made the internal state.

Comment: If this is for a production system needing continuous up time during updates, the usual solution is to use a load-balancer to manage which machines are accessible to public, moving them out of a live pool for updates where they can be re-started without affecting a site being available (you need of course at least two servers to do this, but it can be achieved with VMs on a single host if necessary)